# Modificar un elemento de un array associativo de una colección PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente entrada de datos un array y cada elemento un array associativo

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2022-F1-GP01-RACE
            [year] => 2022
            [family] => F1GP01
            [type] => RACE
            [country] => BHR
            [start_time] => 2022-03-20 15:00:00
            [end_time] => 2022-03-20 17:00:00
            [event] => Bahrain Grand Prix
            [circuit] => BAHRAIN INTERNATIONAL CIRCUIT
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2022-F1-GP02-RACE
            [year] => 2022
            [family] => F1GP02
            [type] => RACE
            [country] => SAU
            [start_time] => 2022-03-27 17:30:00
            [end_time] => 2022-03-27 19:30:00
            [event] => Saudi Arabian Grand Prix
            [circuit] => JEDDAH CORNICHE CIRCUIT
        )
```

Lo que necesito es iterar el array por cada elemento y poder alterar solo el `start_time` para transformarlo en `ISO8601`

Lo que he realizado es obtener en bruto la posición 0 y obtener el valor que hay en 'start_time' para convertir la fecha en ISO8601

```php
$data = $this->dataaccess->rawQuery($sql, $arrparams);
$starTime = $data[0]['start_time'];
$objDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $starTime, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo "Formato:; " . $objDateTime->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . "\n";
```

He mirado un poco la documentación de PHP y con la función `array_map` se podría realizar, pero no ser como armar eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo fácilmente con [`array_walk_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-walk-recursive.php), el cual te permite:

> Aplicar una función de usuario recursivamente a cada miembro de un
> array.

Así, recorrías tu array multidimensional de forma recursiva, creando una función interna que verifique la clave `start_time`, y cambiándola por un objeto `DateTime` con el formato deseado.

Por ejemplo:

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function (&$item, $key) {
    if ($key == 'start_time') {
        $item = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    }
});
```

Ahora `start_time` se verá así:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["start_time"]=>
    object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2022-03-20 15:00:00.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(3) "UTC"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["start_time"]=>
    object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2022-03-27 17:30:00.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(3) "UTC"
    }
  }
}
```

OJO: aquí he optado por almacernar el objeto en sí mismo, pues puede que sea más útil, pero si sólo te interesa una cadena formateada, puedes hacer esto:

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function (&$item, $key) {
    if ($key == 'start_time') {
        $tmp = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $item = $tmp->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
    }
});
```

Y tendrás esto:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["start_time"]=>
    string(24) "2022-03-20T15:00:00+0000"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["start_time"]=>
    string(24) "2022-03-27T17:30:00+0000"
  }
}
```

Comment: La pregunta esta duplicada. te recomiendo evitar responder preguntas duplicadas, o incluso aquellas que aun no hayan sido marcadas como duplicadas pero que encuentres respuestas similares. es posible que otros usuario te den votos negativos. saludos